# Line drawing and WPF anti-aliasing

Tags: .net, wpf, drawing

I'm rendering some line geometries in a WPF canvas. When two lines are overlapped, I get the following undesired drawing:

[image]

As you can see the overlapping is notably visible. I tried to use:

```
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(myLine, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

Now the overlapped lines are not noticiable, but the arrow heads are really poor. This solution is not valid for me:

[image]

I also tried to [SnapsToDevicePixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels(v=vs.110).aspx) and [UseLayoutRounding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.uselayoutrounding(v=vs.95).aspx) properties:

```
myLine.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
myLine.UseLayoutRounding = true;
```

I had no success.

Is there any way to make the overlapped line not noticeable, but maintaining the antialias quality?

### UPDATE

The source of the example is available [here](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/a56c919677e396ec17a99cd06ff9421220160623145743/ef3a14eeaadf841b19bd68e0d4ede0d420160623145743/ce4bc6).

Comment: You cannot use anti-aliasing if you're drawing two objects on top of one another. The anti-aliasing effect works based on the background pixels, and when you draw the second object, it is anti-aliased based on the first object's background pixels. Why do you need to draw two lines on top of one another? Can't you just modify your drawing code so that this is not a problem?

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes, I could. But I'm trying to avoid this. The algorithm to calculate connections now it's trivial. If I need to calculate when lines are crossed or overlapped, that would be more complicated :-(